# How to perform segue smoothly to a view controller after logged in using Google in Firebase Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner. I am trying to implement Google sign in Firebase authentication in iOS app. After the user pressed the login button in my first view controller (red background color), then the user will login using their google account. If it is successful then they will go to the main page (blue background color). I manage the transition using `login` method that I create in the `AppDelegate`.

But the result seems ugly, because after login using google account, the user seems back again to the red background view controller before eventually (after taking some time) move to blue background view controller. Like this

[image]

https://ibb.co/bvQ2rm (here is the link if the .gif doesn't appear)

How to make segue directly to blue background? Or if it is inevitable where should I put activity indicator in my code?

Here is the code I use:

In `AppDelegate`

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()


    // For Google SignIn Using Firebase
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}




// MARK : - Firebase Google Sign In Authentication Methods


@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
        print("failed to login into google")
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    print("user successfully signin into google")

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)


    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("failed to create firebase user using google account")
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }


        // TODO: - Save user data to Firebase database

        print("successfully loggin user to firebase")
        self.login()

    }

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
}


func login () {
    // refer to our Main.storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


    let mainPage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainPage")

    // present tabBar that is storing in tabBar var
    window?.rootViewController = mainPage
}



}
```

Red background view controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var gooleButton: GIDSignInButton! 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self


    }


    @IBAction func googleButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you should do here:

1. Use Activity indicator view to show progress when user taps the sign-in button and remove it either when login is success or failed. User will come back to your red screen anyways so you will have to show some loading message till the time your delegates fire.
2. The Blue screen appears without animation is due to the use of this code: 
   `window?.rootViewController = mainPage`

You can use an animation when you are changing the `rootViewController` as by default it is shown without animation.
You can use the following code as a reference to do it:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabbar")
vc.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    window.rootViewController = vc
}, completion: { completed in
    // maybe do something here
})
```

Hope it helps.